# "You're close to a new privilege: create chat rooms on webapps for 1,000 reputation."

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Given that chat.stackexchange.com privileges are way more complicated than checking a single site's rep score against a number, maybe the app should refrain from announcing chat milestones.

[image]

Comment: Strange, your freehand circle disappears when I view the larger image.

Comment: Freehand wasn't initially there, so probably caching or some such?

Comment: @Cody lovingly added the circle for me but didn't edit the links all the way, hence the confusion.

Comment: Err, oops. I improved a suggested edit that added the circle, but thought the preview was awfully small so I added a link to the larger version. It didn't even occur to me that there wasn't a freehand circle on it.

Comment: Yeah... we should probably only be announcing chat privs on the first site they're relevant on.  I'll take a look.

Comment: @Kevin any update, 12 days later? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I know what and how I want to fix this... just haven't had time yet, unfortunately.  Looks like next week maybe.

Comment: @Kevin sounds good, maybe [meta-tag:status-planned] this so you won't forget? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed a long time ago, sorry about forgetting to update here.